# Решить задачу без простого перебора в массиве, сохраняя только состояние между запросами

Tags: java, алгоритм

> Задан массив, состоящий из `n` целых чисел: `a[1]`, `a[2]`, ..., `a[n]`, по умолчанию заполнены нулями. Более того, заданы m запросов, каждый из которых характеризуется тремя числами `li`, `ri`, `ki`. Запрос `li`, `ri`, `ki` обозначает, что нужно добавить к каждому элементу `a[j]`, где `li` ≤ `j` ≤ `ri`, число `Ckij - li + ki`.
>
> Запись `Cxy` обозначает биномиальный коэффициент, или количество сочетаний из `y` элементов по `x` элементов.
>
> Вам нужно выполнить последовательно все запросы и вывести, чему будут равны элементы массива в итоге, после всех запросов.
>
> Входные данные
>   В первой строке заданы целые числа `n`, `m` (1 ≤ `n`, `m` ≤ 105).
>
> Во второй строке задано `n` целых чисел `a[1]`, `a[2]`, ..., `a[n]` (0 ≤ `ai` ≤ 109) — изначальное состояние массива.
>
> В следующих `m` строках заданы запросы в формате `li`, `ri`, `ki` — прибавить всем элементам отрезка `li`...`ri` число `Ckij - li + ki` (1 ≤ `li` ≤ `ri` ≤ n; 0 ≤ `k` ≤ 100).
>
> Выходные данные
>   Максимальное число из полученного массива

Можно ли как то решить эту задачу кроме как простого перебора в массиве, сохраняя только состояние между запросами? цель задачи не используя массив arr, так как изначально в массиве arr только нули, найти максимальное значение.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int[] first = new int[3];
    first[0] = 1;
    first[1] = 2;
    first[2] = 3;
    int[] last = new int[3];
    last[0] = 2;
    last[1] = 4;
    last[2] = 5;
    int[] value = new int[3];
    value[0] = 45;
    value[1] = 55;
    value[2] = 41;
    int[] arr = new int[6];
    System.out.println(maxValue(arr, first, last, value));
}
private static int maxValue(int[] arr, int first[], int last[], int[] value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
        for (int j = first[i] - 1; i < last[i]; i++) {
            arr[j] += value[j];
        }
    }
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    return arr[0];
}
```

}

Comment: а чем вам здесь не нравится простой перебор?

Comment: сказали что можно по другому сделать, это слишком просто

Comment: Невозможно понять что за проблема у вас. Добавьте больше деталей: пример кода, который можно было запустить, примеры входных и выходных данных. Подробный и чёткий ответ можно дать только на чёткий и подробный вопрос.

Comment: Входные данные добавили, спасибо. Выходных данных так и нет.

Comment: Явная ошибка: first[0] = 1;
    first[0] = 2;
    first[0] = 3; Ты присваиваешь 1му элементу значение 3 раза

Comment: @AlexanderBelov Наоборот слишком сложно. Чтобы найти максимум не нужно сортировать массив

Comment: @rodgers исправил

Comment: кажется ваш пример с "простым перебором" не соответствует условию: 1) входные данные должны вводиться а не хардкодится, но это еще можно списать на упрощенный тест, 2) вы прибавляете к элементам массива только "ki" вместо "Ckij - li + ki" 3) в условии изначальное состояние массива не нули: "Во второй строке задано n целых чисел a[1], a[2], ..., a[n] (0 ≤ ai ≤ 109) — изначальное состояние массива." (!)

Comment: Ответ дал. Помог?

Comment: @rodgers спасибо, но тут используется хэшмап, хуже чем использовать массив

Comment: @AlexanderBelov синтетический пример какой то получается, в котором главное не использоваться что-то а не добиться выполнения, в моём примере возможно любое пересечение отрезков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если отрезки [li, ri] полностью покрывают отрезок [1, n] и значения элементов массива arr могут только увеличиваться (что вроде как соответствует условию задачи), то всё просто:

```
private static int maxValue(int[] arr, int first[], int last[], int[] value) {
    int max = arr[0]; // предполагаемый максимум в первом элементе
    for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
        for (int j = first[i] - 1; i < last[i]; i++) {
            arr[j] += value[j];
            if (max < arr[j]) max = arr[j]; // каждый раз обновляем максимум при необходимости
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Хотя не уверен в правильном понимании условия задачи, но раз без массива, так без массива. При условии, что отрезки [l, r] не пересекаются, всё сводится к поиску максимального значения в массиве value + 0. А больше ничего на фиг не нужно:

```
private static int maxValue(int[] value) {
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        if (max < value[i]) max = value[i];
    }
    return max;
}
```

Но сдаётся мне, что не может быть такого бредового задания. Либо лыжи не едут, либо одно из двух...

Comment: Спасибо, по другому, но я описывал задачу, чтобы без arr найти ответ, добавил в описание что массив arr состоит из нулей, так что смысла его использовать нету, мне так объяснили.

Comment: Вам надо определиться с условиями задачи. В одном месте пишите, что все они == 0, в другом задано n чисел - изначальное состояние. Если нули и отрезки [l, r] не пересекаются, то действительно можно обойтись без массива.

Comment: извините. не правильно описал, а как это сделать без массива

Comment: подскажите как, если вы знаете

Comment: @AlexanderBelov answer updated

Answer (score -1):

Если нельзя использовать массивы как насчёт HashMap? В конце метода можно так же вывести всё его содержимое если нужно.

```
 public static void main(String[] arg) {
    int[] first = new int[3];
    first[0] = 1;
    first[1] = 2;
    first[2] = 3;
    int[] last = new int[3];
    last[0] = 2;
    last[1] = 4;
    last[2] = 5;
    int[] value = new int[3];
    value[0] = 45;
    value[1] = 55;
    value[2] = 41;
  System.out.println(getMax(first,last,value));
}

static int getMax(int first[], int last[], int[] value) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); // Key это номер в массиве, значение накапливаем
    for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {  // проходим по массиву запросов
        for (int j = first[i]; j <= last[i]; j++) { // проходим по значениям запроса
            map.put(j, map.containsKey(j)? map.get(j) + value[i]:value[i]); // складываем значения, если Map не содержит такой ключ, назначаем значение
        }
    }

    return Collections.max(map.values());
}
```